# Access and VBA+SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I started Access programming this morning and stumbled over my first bigger problem which I can't seem to solve.  I've tried quite a few methods (DAO.Recordset e.g.) but it doesn't work.

I want, depending on what is chosen on the Combofield, the list to show the relevant information only.

Further Details: One can search for a specific Storagebin and get the Materials stored on this one listed in a listfield. For this to work I thought I needed to change the recordset of the Listfield every time the user changes the Storagebin in the above searchfield.

Code:

```
Dim findMatSQL As String

findMatSQL = "SELECT Material " & _
             "FROM [tbl_Storagebins] " & _
             "WHERE [tbl_Storagebins].ID = '" & Kombinationsfeld22 & "'"

Me!Liste60.RowSource = findMatSQL
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim findMatSQL As String

findMatSQL = "SELECT Material FROM [tbl_Storagebins] " _
& "WHERE [tbl_Storagebins].ID = " & Me.Kombinationsfeld22

Me!Liste60.RowSource = findMatSQL
Me.Liste60.Requery
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a query using this SQL code

```
SELECT Material FROM [tbl_Storagebins] WHERE [tbl_Storagebins].ID = Forms![yourformnamehere]![Kombinationsfeld22]
```

Do not forget to set [yourformnamehere] to your actual form name.
Then set the row source in liste60 to the query you created.
In the afterupdate event for Kombinationsfeld22 
set it to:

```
Private Sub Kombinationsfeld22_AfterUpdate()
Me.Liste60.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll be trying this one as soon as im back to work. I Really hope this works. Havent thought about doing it this way

Comment: I've tried the method you showed me but somehow the list stays empty and i don't know why. Maybe i am missing something.. heres my Code so far.

Comment: `Private Sub Kombinationsfeld22_AfterUpdate()

Dim tempQuery As DAO.QueryDef
Dim querySQL As String

If queryExists(tempQuery) = True Then
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "tempUmlagerQuery"
End If

querySQL = "SELECT Material " & _
"FROM[tbl_storagebins] " & _
"WHERE[tbl_Storagebins].ID = " & Forms!Umlagern!Kombinationsfeld22 & ""

Set tempQuery = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef _
("tempUmlagerQuery", querySQL)
Form_Umlagern.Liste60.RowSource = "SELECT Material FROM tempUmlagerQuery"


Form_Umlagern.Liste60.Requery
Me.Repaint

End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

I have failed myself! Thanks for all the help from you both, the fault was never the Code, rather did i have set up 2 columns in my List where only 1 was there for real so it appeared empty..